# Reading/Accessing a file owned by user account which is under a directory that is owned by root

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I have a ssh only user account called `pgbackrest` with disabled password .
I have created a directory /etc/pgbackrest/ as root (`sudo mkdir -p /etc/pgbackrest`). Then I create a config file under the above directory and changed the ownership to the account `pgbackrest` and `sudo chmod 640 /etc/pgbackrest/pgbackrest.conf`
When I try to edit it with

1. Switch to `pgbackrest` user `sudo su - pgbackrest` and `vim /etc/pgbackrest/pgbackrest.conf`, I get `/etc/pgbackrest/pgbackrest.conf" [Permission Denied]` in the vim editor.
2. `sudo -u pgbackrest vim /etc/pgbackrest/pgbackrest.conf`, I get `/etc/pgbackrest/pgbackrest.conf" [Permission Denied]` in the vim editor.

does the permissions on the upper level directory prohibit the edit ? 640 means the owner and the group members can read, write. I am accessing the file as the owner, why am I getting access denied ?

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory?  In order to access the file, the `pgbackrest` user has to be able to have _at least_ `x` permissions to the directory.  To get a listing then it also needs `r`.  And to create files (eg temp files) it also needs `w`.  So, yes, directory permissions matter.

Comment: @StephenHarris `drwxr-x---   3 root root       4096 Aug 10 22:56 pgbackrest` on the file `-rw-r-----   1 pgbackrest pgbackrest    0 Aug 10 01:12 pgbackrest.conf`. Is it a good idea to own the `/etc/pgbackrest` to pgbackrest user ? considering the fact that it is under a system directory.

Comment: You could possibly just go `chmod a+x /etc/pgbackrest` so that anyone can see files they have permission to in that directory... _if_ they know the name.

Comment: @StephenHarris Thank you.

Comment: I've made this into a full answer.  Hopefully it makes sense to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a user to be able to access a file, they also need permissions on all the directories in the path leading to the file.

At a bare minimum they need `x` permissions on the directory.

In your case (from comments) you have

```
drwxr-x---   3 root root       4096 Aug 10 22:56 pgbackrest
```

And the file itself:

```
-rw-r-----   1 pgbackrest pgbackrest    0 Aug 10 01:12 pgbackrest.conf
```

This means the `pgbackrest` user can not get to the file to read it.

A simple solution would be to add `x` permissions:

```
chmod a+x /etc/pgbackrest
```

Now anyone who knows the name of the file in that directory could *try* to access the file but the file permissions also take effect.  So only the `pgbackrest` user or anyone in the `pgbackrest` group will be able to open the file; everyone else will be blocked.